# Is there a way to construct a triple border with the middle and innermost border lines spanning only two out of four corners?

Tags: css, border

I want to create following border.

[image]

On outside - solid white border with rounded corners via border radius.
On middle - corner only solid white border with rounded corners visible only on top-left and bottom-right corners of border.
On innermost - corner only solid white border with rounded corners fitting into max lenght of middle border visible only on top-left and bottom-right corners of border.

I have tried to apply this to a single border with after and before ccs and this allows me to easily create up to three lines but I cannot style the inner and middle one as I wish.

Current state of code:

```
.corner-adored-white-border {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    margin: 10px;
}

.corner-adored-white-border:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 2px;
    bottom: 2px;
    left: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

.corner-adored-white-border:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    bottom: 5px;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    border-radius: 8px;
}
```

As you see the current result doesn't give me exact border I want on inside and middle lines.

Comment: can you share a screen .. it's harder to keep all the information and imagine it

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/virCwg2 - This is my desired result. (can't edit the post for some reason).

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea with pseudo element and box shadow

```css
.box {
  width:250px;
  height:100px;
  border:2px solid;
  border-radius:10px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:0;
}
.box:before,
.box:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  border:2px solid;
}
.box:before {
 top:5px;
 left:5px;
 border-right:0;
 border-bottom:0;
 border-top-left-radius:10px;
 box-shadow: 
  5px 5px 0 inset #fff, 
  7px 7px 0 inset #000;
}
.box:after {
 bottom:5px;
 right:5px;
 border-left:0;
 border-top:0;
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 box-shadow: 
  -5px -5px 0 inset #fff, 
  -7px -7px 0 inset #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```